# Sage 300 (accpac) SDATA Create Customer

Tags: erp, accpac, sdata

I'm trying to use SDATA to create a customer but can't seem to find the proper endpoint.  I've scoured the schema and have only found wkshpcustomer, but nobody seems to know what that object is.

I can, however, create an order without issue:

```
[POST] http://{domain}/SDataServlet/sdata/sageERP/accpac/{company}/oeorders/
```

```xml
<sdata:payload>
    <oeorder xmlns="schemas.sage.com/sageERP">
        <TERMS>CASH</TERMS>
        <CUSTOMER></CUSTOMER>
    </oeorder>
</sdata:payload>
```

When I do the same based on the following blog post (https://smist08.wordpress.com/2011/08/06/fun-with-sdata/) for creating a customer, I get the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <sdata:diagnoses xmlns:sdata="schemas.sage.com/.../1">
        <sdata:diagnosis>
            <sdata:severity>error</sdata:severity>
            <sdata:sdataCode>ResourceKindNotFound</sdata:sdataCode>
            <sdata:message>Resource kind: CUSTOMER cannot be found in the classMap.</sdata:message>
        </sdata:diagnosis>
    </sdata:diagnoses>
```

So, how do I create a customer using SDATA?

Comment: Please see if the link helps - https://smist08.wordpress.com/2012/03/03/defining-sdata-feeds-for-sage-300-erp/

Comment: Right, so CUSTOMER/CUSTOMERS isn't present in our classmap. Any thoughts on why that might be?

Comment: It's not present doesn't mean it ever was, try a completely made up one and you will likely get the same result. Have you tried `<protocol>://<hostname>:<port>/sdata/$system/registry/endpoints` to see what endpoints are registered? http://sage.github.io/SData-2.0/pages/core/1403/

Comment: Never used Sage 300 ERP but looks like the implementation is different as the link @Rao has suggested describes in detail.

Comment: I have pulled the classmap. On mobile now but will add link out. The only customer related entity is called wkshpcustomer which doesn't mean anything to me